# Form encoded data (Solve360 API)

Tags: json, post

I'm trying to upload a file with a [Web API](http://norada.com/answers/api/external_api_introduction) using Json. In the documentation it is stated that the file (field) must be uploaded in form encoded data.

Is it possible to have form encoded data inside a Json POST request or the whole request must be in form encoded data? I tried many things and Solve360 help desk is unresponsive...

I was imagining something like this would work but no:

{"parent":"10254222","data":{"caption":"test","file":"this+is+a+test"}}

and the same request in form encoded data isn't working either:

parent=10254222&data%5Bcaption%5D=test&data%5Bfile%5D=this+is+a+test

thanks

Comment: Do you specify content-type header correctly? Applicaion/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: yes I do specify the header type correctly...

Comment: Could you provide the form (or at least a stripped down version of it?) and also the method you're using to json encode and send the data?

Comment: Did you managed to get this working?

Comment: No, but my intern is over so I don't need to solve it anymore.